# Convert tab separated value CSV to comma separated values in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a large CSV file that's all tab separated/tab delimited throughout. What's the easiest way to convert it to comma separated using R?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Read it with `read.delim` and then write it with `write.csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it in using readLines, convert the tabs to commas and write it out:

```
writeLines(gsub("\t", ",", readLines("myfile.tab")), "myfile.csv")
```